# Find $h(x) = x f(x)$, if $f (0) = -2$, and $f'(0) = 3$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I am not too sure about how I should approach this question, but it seemed like an interesting one when I discovered it.

Comment: Is this everything in the question? Because $f(x)=3x-2$ implies $h=3x^2-2x$ but $f(x)=-2e^{-1.5x}$ says other things about $h$

Comment: Are you sure this is the question? Perhaps the question wants you to evaluate $h'(0)$? That would make more sense...

Comment: If $f(0) = -2$ then $f^\prime(0)=0\neq 3$ since $-2=-2\times 1 =-2\cdot x^0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @user477343 I gave 2 examples where those conditions hold, and I can't give how many more you would like. This is a point, we can't determine the derivative of a point without the function, otherwise every function's derivative will be $0$

Comment: @Holo sorry I didn't read your comment. I was in a rush to go to the bathroom so I just quickly commented. I didn't mean to make you angry. Thanks for the note, though. I didn't realise...

Comment: @user477343 It is natural to have mistakes and the only time I'll be angry about mistake is if it is my mistake. I just wanted to correct you. If I sounded angry: my apologies

Comment: @Holo no problem. Words don't have faces on them for you to know what someone means when they write something, and besides, I think my teacher said what you have said :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is analytical at zero, you know that
$$
f(x)=-2+3x+x^2g(x)
$$
for any $g$ analytical at zero. Now
$$
h(x)=xf(x)=-2x+3x^2+x^3g(x).
$$
Without more information, all you can discover here is $h(0)$, $h'(0)$ and $h''(0)$.